# Expanding the index of an xts object

Tags: r, xts

I want to create an xts objects with indices from other xts objects, but enhanced , i.e. longer : before start and after end.
E.g. for adding 5 periods after the corresponding index, I'll use:

```
data(sample_matrix)
xts_object <- as.xts(sample_matrix, descr='my new xts object')

add_right <- 5
seq(as.Date(end(xts_object)), by = unclass(periodicity(xts_object))$label, length = (add_right+1))[-1]
```

2 Questions:

1. Does this always work (I'll use it inside functions)
2. How do I add periods before the corresponding start?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*1. Does this always work (I'll use it inside functions)*

Yes.

*2. How do I add periods before the corresponding start?*

Here is an example of expanding the index on both the start and end boundaries, using `NA` values by default to fill.  You can also easily add actual xts data at the start or end using `rbind(xts1, xts2)` provided the columns of the data match.

```
# add dateFormat = "Date" to avoid misaligned timestamps
# in relation to time component HH:MM:SS when `rbind`ing with
# Date type indexes (as opposed to POSIXct type indexes):
xts_object <- as.xts(sample_matrix, descr='my new xts object', dateFormat="Date") 

my_periodicity <- unclass(periodicity(xts_object))$label
add_right <- 5
v_dates_end <- seq(as.Date(end(xts_object)),
                   by = my_periodicity,
                   length.out = (add_right+1))[-1]

st_date <- as.Date(start(xts_object))
v_dates_start <- seq(from = st_date - 5,
                     to = st_date - 1,
                     by = my_periodicity)

x_expand_time_index <- xts(, order.by = c(v_dates_start, v_dates_end))
# Note the fill argument could be replaced by say 0, 1, NaN, etc
x <- merge(xts_object, x_expand_time_index, fill = NA)

head(x)
#                Open     High      Low    Close
# 2006-12-28       NA       NA       NA       NA
# 2006-12-29       NA       NA       NA       NA
# 2006-12-30       NA       NA       NA       NA
# 2006-12-31       NA       NA       NA       NA
# 2007-01-01       NA       NA       NA       NA
# 2007-01-02 50.03978 50.11778 49.95041 50.11778
tail(x)
#                Open     High      Low    Close
# 2007-06-30 47.67468 47.94127 47.67468 47.76719
# 2007-07-01       NA       NA       NA       NA
# 2007-07-02       NA       NA       NA       NA
# 2007-07-03       NA       NA       NA       NA
# 2007-07-04       NA       NA       NA       NA
# 2007-07-05       NA       NA       NA       NA
```